# Move Toplevel with place geometry manager

Tags: python, tkinter

Once an application has been created and displayed on the screen, is it possible to move the application to a different location on the screen?

I have a library function which places the application or a Toplevel frame like this

```
def create_top_window(master, node, center=True):
    if not master:
        master = TK.Toplevel()
    if center:
        center_window(master, node.width, node.height)
    node.widget = TK.Frame(master, relief=node.relief)
    node.widget.place(x=node.x, y=node.y,width=node.width, height=node.height)

def center_window(root, w=300, h=200): # Center main application window
    # set screen width and height
    ws = root.winfo_screenwidth()
    hs = root.winfo_screenheight()
    # calculate position x, y
    x = (ws/2) - (w/2)
    y = (hs/2) - (h/2)
    root.geometry('%dx%d+%d+%d' % (w, h, x, y))
```

The node is an object with other attributes other than those needed by the widget - and will contain the required size of the application.

I tried calling place again but that did nothing.
How do I change the position on the screen at a later date in the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`place` is strictly for locating widgets within other widgets.

To move a toplevel or root window you can use the [geometry](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/wm.htm#Tkinter.Wm.geometry-method) command. For example, to move a window to the upper-left corner you can to this:

```
root.geometry("+0+0")
```

Comment: @jimscafe See http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/geometry.html for geometry string doc.